# jmvc 3.2.2 - Controller Inheritance and steal load order

Tags: javascriptmvc

I have a base Controller in folder
[app]/main/create_parent/create_parent.js

defined as

```
        $.Controller('Impress.Main.CreateParent',
```

I have have several child controllers extending CreateParent e.g
[app]/contact/create/create.js

defined as

```
        Impress.Main.CreateParent('Impress.Contact.Create',
```

This all works well(mostly) uncomprressed , randomly I get errors saying that it can't find the base controller....
Once compressed and packaged, I consistently get the error saying that the base controller is not defined.

This is obvioulsy due to a steal load order issue.
In my main [app name].js I have:

```
    steal('jquery')
       .then('./resources/jquery-ui', './resources/image_uploader')
       .then('jquery/controller/subscribe')
       .then(
    'impress/main/create_parent','impress/main/list_parent')
       .then(
          './impress.css', // application CSS file
          './models/models.js', // steals all your models
          'impress/contact/create',
       ...
```

So I have "stolen" the base eate parent first "then" the rest of the controllers...
So it seems I have done it correctly? Even when I steal the basec controller in my contact/create/create.js file first, it still complains.

So again, this all works fine on most loads when uncompressed all though randomly I do get the error, but once compressed it is consistent.
I am clearly misunderstanding steal's functionality as I thought that the "then" syntax was to define load order?

Thanks
Hans

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem which was caused by overriding of the string.split function.